# When I move or scale objects, keyframes are being added

Tags: keyframes

When I move, for example, my camera's view to a different place on the timeline, keyframes are being added even if I don't press <kbd>i</kbd>. Same thing if I move or scale an object. It never happened before, so I've probably changed a setting but I don't know which?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have probably set auto-keyframing on.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, it was enabled!! I learn a new trick today, thanks sir ;)

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you accidentally enabled Auto Keying. In the Timeline, uncheck the first icon (the circle) of the animation controls :

[image: animation controls]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! sorry but I can't also check your answer as the good answer!